# How to save information about page on redirect in Laravel Blade View in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-9

In Laravel 9 I've got 2 tables, one inside of another.
[image]
To avoid second table from taking too much space, by default, it's display is set to none and can be "rolled out" when button is pressed

```xml
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-warning"
  id="hidden{{ $buttonIndex }}"
  onclick="
    $('.items{{ $buttonIndex }}').slideToggle(function() {
      $('#hidden{{ $buttonIndex }}')
        .html(
          $('.items{{ $buttonIndex }}').is(':visible')
            ? 'Roll'
            : 'Rollout'
        );
    });"
>Rollout</button>
```

but when I refresh the page or do any CRUD operation, opened tabs are getting closed again.

Is there any way to keep them opened after page refresh?

**I tried my way with AJAX**, but if I would like to use it, I will need to rebuild whole CRUD operations and view, so I would prefer to avoid it.

**Other way I'm about to try** is to send button ID data on request, so in case it would be clicked, it will appear in the request(or url), but I've got no idea how to achieve it yet.

**How can I keep second table opened on page refresh/reload**

Comment: if i would do this based on your requirement, i would have a hidden textbox, wherein it would change value based on the rolled-out action. so if i would make a CRUD operation, i would always check the value of that hidden textbox and then decide if it should be rolled out or not during page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Session Storage is perfect for your use case

From [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> `Window.sessionStorage`
>
> The read-only `sessionStorage` property accesses a session [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object for the current [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin). `sessionStorage` is similar to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage); the difference is that while data in `localStorage` doesn't expire, data in `sessionStorage` is cleared when the page session ends.
>
> - Whenever a document is loaded in a particular tab in the browser, a unique page session gets created and assigned to that particular tab. That page session is valid only for that particular tab.
> - A page session lasts as long as the tab or the browser is open, **and survives over page reloads and restores**.
> - Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
> - Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates `sessionStorage` for each tab/window.
> - Duplicating a tab copies the tab's `sessionStorage` into the new tab.
> - Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in `sessionStorage`.

Let's say your table is in a div like this.

```xml
<div id="hidden-table-{{ $index }}" class="hidden-table">
</div>
```

In your jquery, you get set its display based on some `sessionStorage` key.

```js
$(() => {
    $('.hidden-table').each(element => {
        (sessionStorage.getItem('should-show-'+$(element).attr('id')) !== null)
            ? $(element).show()
            : $(element).hide();
    });
})
```

For this to work, you need to set this sessionStorage item whenever you're showing the table.

```
// show table with id 'table-id'
sessionStorage.setItem('should-show-table-id', true); // or anything that isn't null really.
```

And remove the key when you're hiding it

```
// hide table with id 'table-id'
sessionStorage.removeItem('should-show-table-id'); // removes the key. Using getItem on a key that doesn't exist returns null, so that works just fine.
```